# Convert from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I want to convert Oracle to SQL Server:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(@PV_DEMOG_FILE_NAME, '([^.]+)')
```

Comment: You seem to have mistaken Stack Overlfow for a free code-writing service. What research have you done into this?

Comment: Since you are looking for a string that doesn't contain a period (I think that's what that regex says) you may be able to use `parsename` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. Like `PARSENAME(<columnname>, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm wrong, that returns file name without its extension. If that'so, in Oracle you'd get e.g.

```
SQL> with test (file_name) as
  2    (select 'c:\temp\test.csv' from dual)
  3  select REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_name, '([^.]+)') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
------------
c:\temp\test

SQL>
```

Similarly (although I don't speak MS SQL Server), `substring` that looks like this might help:

```
with test as 
  (select 'c:\temp\test.txt' as file_name)
select substring(file_name, 1, charindex('.', file_name) - 1) as result
from test;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys for quick reply i will check

Comment: `NULLIF(charindex('.', file_name), 0)` might be wise in case it can't find the substring